# how to make a responsive span

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix this issue that i'm facing is that I need a span to view the name of the picture but the problem is when I insert a long name like `bullet rounds` it makes the picture not clear so I want to fix this problem without changing the font size or anything else, any suggestion?

[image]

```
<div class="card holder">
    <div class="card-body">
        <img src="icons\bullet.png" style="position:absolute;left:15%;width:40px; height:36px;" alt="">
        <h4 id="counter">1</h4>
    </div>
    <span class="itemname">9mm. Rounds</span>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.holder {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.534);
    height:65px;
    width:59px;
}
.itemname{
    font-family:boto;
    font-size:7px;
    margin-top:-22%;
    color:white;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.863) !important;
}
```

Comment: can you provide codedanbox url?

Comment: If it doesn't fit, something has to give. What would you like it to do when it doesn't fit?

Comment: "either increase the height of the span's parent element or increase the height of the span and bring it on top of the image using z-index , or limit the number of characters or hide the overflowing text characters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things.
One this is when overflowing the content you can limit it content and add ... ath the end of the content.[see the reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

you can add below code to the itemname class.Remenber to add max width propety.

```
.itemname{
    font-family:boto;
    font-size:7px;
    margin-top:-22%;
    color:white;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.863) !important;
    overflow: "hidden",
    textOverflow: " ellipsis",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    maxWidth: "100%",
}
```

Other thing that you can do is,you can set span with class ".itemname" to opacity zero and  when hovering over the card(.holder class),make .itemname card opacity 1.

```
.itemname{
    font-family:boto;
    font-size:7px;
    margin-top:-22%;
    color:white;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.863) !important;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.holder:hover .itemname{

 opacity:1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If are okay to crop the overflowing text with ... indicator you could try text-overflow: ellipsis css property.